# Where is the texture cache located in a GPU?

Tags: textures, opencl, gpu

I'm starting with OpenCL programming and learning about the differences between a texture buffer (also called image) and a regular buffer. From what I undersand, one of these differences is the fact that a texture fetch is cached, and with 2D locality.

The question is: where is this texture cache located? Is it shared across threads or is it just useful for accesses within a single thread?

For instance, consider this kernel:

```
__constant sampler_t sampler = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE | CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;

__kernel void myCoolKernel( __read_only image2d_t image, __global float * dst) {
        const int i = get_global_id(0);
        const int j = get_global_id(1);
        dst[i+j*get_global_size(0)] = read_imagef(image, sampler, (int2){i,j}).x;
}
```

Will *nearby* threads (on the same work-group I guess?) take advantage of the image cache? Or is it more useful for a kernel like the one below?

```
__kernel void myCoolKernel( __read_only image2d_t image, __global float * dst) {
        // Pray it's not a boundary
        const int i = get_global_id(0);
        const int j = get_global_id(1);
        float pixel1 = read_imagef(image, sampler, (int2){i+1,j}).x;
        float pixel2 = read_imagef(image, sampler, (int2){i,j-1}).x;
        float pixel3 = read_imagef(image, sampler, (int2){i-1,j}).x;
        float pixel4 = read_imagef(image, sampler, (int2){i,j+1}).x;
        dst[i+j*get_global_size(0)] = pixel1+pixel2+pixel3+pixel4;
}
```

I hope I made myself clear. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

It is shared between threads. It exists because of graphics API textures (e.g., OpenGL, DirectX, Vulkan, etc.) but OpenCL images can use it too. It typically has 2D locality, probably due to Z-order storage. It is much faster than non-coalesced buffer access, but maybe not as fast as coalesced buffer access.

Comment: How is it shared? Is it the same cache for all running threads? Or within a work-group?

Answer (score 1):

It'll be GPU dependent. For example, some systems may have several "independent" shader "units", each of which will be running a *subset* of all available threads. Each shader unit will probably have its own L0 texture cache so that all threads assigned to that unit will be sharing that cache.

However, like a CPU, there will probably be a cache hierarchy such that there's an L1 cache that feeds the multiple shader unit L0s.

So to answer your question...

> Will nearby threads (on the same work-group I guess?) take advantage of the image cache?

... yes, if the accesses of the threads as a set are coherent, then it will take advantage of the cache hierarchy.

FWIW there's a little more on texture caches usage on [the computer graphics site](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/357/is-using-many-texture-maps-bad-for-caching)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which threads are going to be in the same shader unit? Ones with close global ID?

Comment: I couldn't really say. I know roughly what goes on with the GPUs I've helped develop but no idea what other vendors would be doing.